# Webflux nested subscribe performance and limitations

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm creating a WebFlux reactive-based background service that scans a directory for files, and then process each file.

The scanning operation returns a `Flux<LogArchive>` instance, and then the `LogArchive` instance has a `read()` method which returns a `Flux<LogSource>` with the logs that it contains, so that we can process each of them.

The current code that initiate it is the following:

```
    listener.listen()
                .doOnError(e -> LOG.error("Error occurred while listening to the new log archives", e))
                .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(LISTEN_NEW_ARCHIVES_MAX_ATTEMPTS, LISTEN_NEW_ARCHIVES_MIN_BACKOFF))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .subscribe(archive -> {
                    archive.read()
                            .doOnNext(source -> LOG.info("Starting to parse the log source: {}", source))
                            .flatMap(logSourceParser::process)
                            .onErrorResume(LogSourceFormatException.class, e -> 
                            .doOnNext(source -> LOG.info("Finished to parse the log source: {}", source))
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
                            .subscribe();
                });
```

My concern is that this code should run within directories that contains 100k+ files, and thus I'm worried that, as WebFlux will reach the maximum threads limit, it might not be able to handle the processing correctly. Thus my questions:

1. Did I configured the WebFlux subscribers well? I also tried to use `flatMap` instead of a nested `subscribe`, but as it returns multiple items - it didn't work and only processed the first item.
2. Will this configuration be able to handle this workload (assuming scalable resources and well-optimized processing code)?
3. What can be done to optimize this code or to solve this task better?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by _"but as it returns multiple items - it didn't work"_?

Comment: I tried to change my logic from a nested subscriber into `flatMap(archive -> archive.read())` and then run the rest of the nested pipeline on this result. However, as `listener.listen()` returns many `Flux<LogArchive>`, and each of these archives return a `Flux<LogSource>` - it seems like Webflux couldn't handle this transition and only handled the first returned `LogArchive`...

Comment: It can handle that. It should be able to handle infinite amount of items. I guess there is something else in the code that prevents if from an effective processing.